# React Native - hooks useState empty array

Tags: javascript, react-native

Consider the following piece of code in React Native:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [recommendations, setRecommendation] = useState<any[]>([]);
  return (
    <View>
      {recommendations != [] ? 
      (
        <Text>A</Text>
      ) : (
        <Text>B</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Currently this always returns A and never enters B.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short, because the condition `recommendations != []` always evaluates to true. If you want to compare arrays, you'll need to do a deep comparison. This article may be helpful: [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The expression you are using always returns `true`. That's why you get A as output.

If you want to return B when there are no elements in the array and A when there are, you can use the length of the array to achieve this.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [recommendations, setRecommendation] = useState<any[]>([]);
  return (
    <View>
      {recommendations.length ? 
      (
        <Text>A</Text>
      ) : (
        <Text>B</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The MDN documentation says the following about [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators):

> Features of comparisons:
>
> - Two strings are strictly equal when they have the same sequence of characters, same length, and same characters in corresponding
>     positions.
> - Two numbers are strictly equal when they are numerically equal (have the same number value). [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) is not equal to anything,
>     including NaN. Positive and negative zeros are equal to one another.
> - Two Boolean operands are strictly equal if both are `true` or both are `false`.
> - **Two distinct objects are never equal for either strict or abstract comparisons.**
> - **An expression comparing Objects is only true if the operands reference the same Object.**
> - Null and Undefined Types are strictly equal to themselves and abstractly equal to each other.
>
> ...
>
> If **both operands are objects**, then JavaScript compares internal references which are not equal when operands refer to different objects in memory.

Objects are compared by reference. An array is also an object. This means `[] == []` will always result in `false` since they are not the exact same object (with the same reference). This also means `[] != []` will always be `true` for the same reason.

If you want to check for en empty array use the `length` property:

```
<View>
  {recommendations.length ? 
  (
    <Text>Not Empty</Text>
  ) : (
    <Text>Empty</Text>
  )}
</View>
```

This uses the fact that an empty array has `length` `0`, which is falsy. If you rather be more explicit `recommendations.length != 0` would have the same result.